# How to prevent files from being deleted on idling in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have a flask server running on a GAE (flexible env). The application generates certain files during runtime based on the API requests received. But after the instance starts, after idling, the files are lost. How do i prevent this ?

Comment: You need to provide some code so we can try to understand what you're talking about.  What does "generate file" mean?  Where are you storing them?

Comment: @GAEfan the application create certain image files during the runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application seems to write those files on the filesystem. However, whatever is written in the filesystem will not be persisted and will be lost on instance death. Also, what you write in one instance won't be available to other instances serving your app.

The solution to this is to write your files to [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage). Any instance can write and retrieve its files there and they'll be available for any instance of your service.

Comment: Or store them in the datastore if they are reasonably small.

Comment: I need o store the files created into a nested directory structure. It's straightforward with flask running on a local machine, but since I'm new to deploying applications on server, I'm not able to figure it out. I've checked about blob storage. But can a simple solution be designed ? Something similar to os.makedirs() ?